# How to Read CSV file in java using Jackson Library ,JSON

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson, schema

How to Read CSV file from a path in java using Jackson Library. And Parse Using 
  **CsvSchema**,    **ObjectReader**  ,  **CsvMapper**. ANd then convert it to JSON object USing Jackson library. pLease HELP.

```
private void testCsvRead() throws Exception 
 {
   String FILE_NAME = "G://Read folder/output.csv";
   System.out.println("read csv");

   ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

   //-------------*****I am getting error here*****------------///

   File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(FILE_NAME).getFile());

   <-------------**********------------/
   CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder().addColumn("parentCategoryCode").addColumn("code").addColumn("name").addColumn("description").build();
   CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();


   ObjectReader oReader = mapper.readerFor(OfferTemplateCategory.class).with(schema);


   try (Reader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
    MappingIterator mi = oReader.readValues(reader);

       while (mi.hasNext()) 
       {
         System.out.println(mi.next());
       }

  }
}
```

I am getting error on this line(See above)

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(FILE_NAME).getFile());
```

This is the error--->

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at CSVtester.CsvTest.testCsvRead(CsvTest.java:39)
at CSVtester.CsvTest.main(CsvTest.java:26)
```

Comment: And what error is that?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at CSVtester.CsvTest.testCsvRead(CsvTest.java:39)
 at CSVtester.CsvTest.main(CsvTest.java:26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *likely* issue here is that `classLoader.getResource(FILE_NAME)` returns `null`.

As you're using an absolute path for the file, you may want to simplify your code and simply use:

```
File file = new File("G://Read folder/output.csv");
```

You can verify if your file exists by invoking `exists()` on the `File` object.

**Note**

Here's the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) for `Classloader#getResource`, and a likely explanation of why it's `null` in your case.

Comment: Direct loading is working But output shown is 
     CSVtester.OfferTemplateCategory@91161c7
CSVtester.OfferTemplateCategory@604ed9f0
CSVtester.OfferTemplateCategory@6a4f787b

Comment: @shoaibshaikh that means your file is getting loaded (and likely parsed) properly, but what you are printing is the iterated instances of `OfferTemplateCategory`, which I imagine do not override `Object#toString`, hence the `[type@hexadecimal]` default representation. Try printing some of their properties, or debugging your code to see what you want to extract.

Comment: I did try printing properties .I want to print rows with header.