# Issues when reading JSON values from POJO with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, string, jackson

I want to parse JSON String into POJO class but I am getting error.

And 
can we return two values from a method in java

**String data**

```
String PostcreatedMessage = "..."; // see JSON value below
{
    "home_page":"/desk",
    "message":"Logged In",
    "full_name":"Shoaib Shaikh"
}
```

**Main.class**

```
LoginR loginR=new LoginR();

ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

loginR=mapper.readValue(PostcreatedMessage,LoginR.class);
System.out.println(loginR.getHomePage());
System.out.println(loginR.getMessage());
System.out.println(loginR.getFullName());
```

**parsejacker.class**

```
public class parsejacker
 {

    LoginR loginR=null;
    String jsonurl; 

    public parsejacker(String jsonurl) {
        super();
        this.jsonurl = jsonurl;
    }

        public void ParseLogin() throws JsonParseException,JsonMappingException,IOException
        {
                System.out.println(jsonurl+"this parselogin");
                ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
                loginR=mapper.readValue(jsonurl,LoginR.class);
                System.out.println(loginR.getHomePage());
                System.out.println(loginR.getMessage());
                System.out.println(loginR.getFullName());

        }
 }
```

**LoginR.class**

```
  public class LoginR

  {
      private String homePage; 
      private String message; 
      private String fullName; 

          public String getHomePage(){
            return homePage; 
          }
          public void setHomePage(String input){
             this.homePage = input;
          }
          public String getMessage(){
            return message; 
          }
          public void setMessage(String input){
             this.message = input;
          }
          public String getFullName(){
            return fullName; 
          }
          public void setFullName(String input){
             this.fullName = input;
         }
 }
```

**I am Getting these errors.**

(I think the error is in the `PostcreatedMessage` string. 
How to overcome `"home_page":"/desk"`? --> this backslash error i.e delimiting or ignore this char)

```
   Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:

    Unrecognized field "home_page" (Class org.greenshoaib.greenshaikh.login.model.LoginR), not marked as ignorable

at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4738a206; line: 1, column: 15] 

   (through reference chain: org.greenshoaib.greenshaikh.login.model.LoginR["home_page"])

    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
    at org.greenshoaib.greenshaikh.rest.client.RestAPIClient.main(RestAPIClient.java:72       )
```

Comment: On a side note you should work on your coding style, e.g. your variable naming. `PostcreatedMessage` looks like a class name but is probably a variable name - that's why the Java code conventions state that only class names should be written in camel case starting with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON contains a field "home_page" but in your pojo it's called `homePage` (same for "full_name"). Jackson doesn't know the two are equal so you need to help it, e.g. by adding `@JsonProperty("home_page")` to `homePage`, i.e. like this (and remember to do that same for `fullName`):

```
@JsonProperty("home_page")
private String homePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your method with the following json String :

```
PostcreatedMessage {
    "homePage":"/desk",
    "message":"Logged In",
    "fullName":"Shoaib Shaikh"
}
```

Comment: While this would work, developers are usually not at liberty to change the payload, as it would typically come with a form of contract. See other answers decorating the model POJO with annotations, which allows keeping the payload as is, yet using appropriate Java variable naming in the model.

Comment: I know, but that was to check if the issue comes from here. As you said, the real solution is to add `@JsonProperty` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the `ObjectMapper` cannot recognize the properties of your `LoginR` class by name, e.g. `homePage != home_page`.

You can annotate those properties to match their expected JSON key.

Here's a minimal example:

```
public class LoginR {
    @JsonProperty(value="home_page")
    private String homePage;
    @JsonProperty(value="full_name")
    private String fullName;
    // etc. the rest of your POJO
}
```

... somewhere else...

```
String json = "{\"home_page\":\"/desk\",\"message\":\"Logged In\",\"full_name\":\"Shoaib Shaikh\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
LoginR loginR = mapper.readValue(json,LoginR.class);
System.out.println(loginR.getHomePage());
System.out.println(loginR.getMessage());
System.out.println(loginR.getFullName());
```

**Output**

```
/desk
Logged In
Shoaib Shaikh
```

Comment: Mena can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939994/how-to-read-csv-file-in-java-using-jackson-library-json